# Istio + Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, istio

I'm playing with Istio and Elasticsearch, I have virtual box machines on my laptop

I Installed Elastic search from this link [Kubernetes Elasticsearch Cluster](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster)

I have a master es + data es, if I installed them without Istio, they run normally.

If I inject them with Istio the data nodes can not communicate with master (it does not find it).

```
root@node1:/home/arkan# k get all
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7     1/2       Running   1          1m
pod/es-master-6b6d5fd59b-86qpb   2/2       Running   0          1m
NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/elasticsearch             NodePort    10.108.28.225   <none>        9200:32721/TCP   1m
service/elasticsearch-discovery   ClusterIP   None            <none>        9300/TCP         1m
service/kubernetes                ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          22h
NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/es-data     1         1         1            0           1m
deployment.apps/es-master   1         1         1            1           1m
NAME                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.apps/es-data-6fdbcf956f     1         1         0         1m
replicaset.apps/es-master-6b6d5fd59b   1         1         1         1m





root@node1:/home/arkan# k describe pod/es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7
Name:           es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7
Namespace:      default
Node:           node2/192.168.0.214
Start Time:     Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:42:50 +0300
Labels:         component=elasticsearch
                pod-template-hash=2986795129
                role=data
Annotations:    sidecar.istio.io/status={"version":"55c9e544b52e1d4e45d18a58d0b34ba4b72531e45fb6d1572c77191422556ffc","initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"],"volumes":["istio-envoy","istio-certs...
Status:         Running
IP:             172.16.104.22
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/es-data-6fdbcf956f
Init Containers:
  init-sysctl:
    Container ID:  docker://c510035d1e823d134ad287116ef43332255758cce60cc1216ed20282b0b55e76
    Image:         busybox:1.27.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:bbc3a03235220b170ba48a157dd097dd1379299370e1ed99ce976df0355d24f0
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sysctl
      -w
      vm.max_map_count=262144
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:42:52 +0300
      Finished:     Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:42:52 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mkdlq (ro)
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  docker://42a8f5da07834533dcd4c26155fb344fa41edecb744e6a4c14c54c40610a450b
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxy_init:0.8.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxy_init@sha256:b0b288ee8270e054442abdd413da9395e2af39fed1792b85ec157700ef2c192f
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      -p
      15001
      -u
      1337
      -m
      REDIRECT
      -i
      *
      -x

      -b
      9200, 9300,
      -d

    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:42:53 +0300
      Finished:     Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:42:53 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mkdlq (ro)
Containers:
  es-data:
    Container ID:   docker://505269e9be09e83d672b91a582afd7569b3afd794bbfab764d50d75e7a3f7309
    Image:          quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes:6.3.0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes@sha256:dcd3e9db3d2c6b9a448d135aebcacac30a4cca655d42efaa115aa57405cd22f3
    Ports:          9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:46:08 +0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    143
      Started:      Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:45:18 +0300
      Finished:     Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:46:07 +0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Limits:
      cpu:  1
    Requests:
      cpu:      250m
    Liveness:   tcp-socket :transport delay=20s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:http/_cluster/health delay=20s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      NAMESPACE:     default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      NODE_NAME:     es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7 (v1:metadata.name)
      CLUSTER_NAME:  myesdb
      NODE_MASTER:   false
      NODE_INGEST:   false
      HTTP_ENABLE:   true
      ES_JAVA_OPTS:  -Xms256m -Xmx256m
      PROCESSORS:    1 (limits.cpu)
    Mounts:
      /data from storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mkdlq (ro)
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://1bf8e167ece0ac6282c336a6630c292013e36721ba027e6e8b5bb71a4bf65a25
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:0.8.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:1930f0603321b1917b2249c576ecb4141aaceeaae5fcc0760b6a88dc88daea3e
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      --configPath
      /etc/istio/proxy
      --binaryPath
      /usr/local/bin/envoy
      --serviceCluster
      istio-proxy
      --drainDuration
      45s
      --parentShutdownDuration
      1m0s
      --discoveryAddress
      istio-pilot.istio-system:15007
      --discoveryRefreshDelay
      10s
      --zipkinAddress
      zipkin.istio-system:9411
      --connectTimeout
      10s
      --statsdUdpAddress
      istio-statsd-prom-bridge.istio-system:9125
      --proxyAdminPort
      15000
      --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
      NONE
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:46:37 +0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:42:55 +0300
      Finished:     Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:46:36 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  128Mi
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:                      es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                 default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                    (v1:status.podIP)
      ISTIO_META_POD_NAME:           es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7 (v1:metadata.name)
      ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE:  REDIRECT
    Mounts:
      /etc/certs/ from istio-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mkdlq (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  storage:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  
  istio-envoy:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  Memory
  istio-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio.default
    Optional:    true
  default-token-mkdlq:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mkdlq
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7 to node2
  Normal   Pulled     5m                kubelet, node2     Container image "busybox:1.27.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5m                kubelet, node2     Created container
  Normal   Started    5m                kubelet, node2     Started container
  Normal   Started    5m                kubelet, node2     Started container
  Normal   Pulled     5m                kubelet, node2     Container image "docker.io/istio/proxy_init:0.8.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5m                kubelet, node2     Created container
  Normal   Pulled     5m                kubelet, node2     Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:0.8.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5m                kubelet, node2     Created container
  Normal   Started    5m                kubelet, node2     Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m                kubelet, node2     Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 172.16.104.22:9300: connect: invalid argument
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m                kubelet, node2     Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.16.104.22:9200/_cluster/health: dial tcp 172.16.104.22:9200: connect: invalid argument
  Normal   Pulled     5m (x2 over 5m)   kubelet, node2     Container image "quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes:6.3.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5m (x2 over 5m)   kubelet, node2     Created container
  Normal   Killing    5m                kubelet, node2     Killing container with id docker://es-data:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Normal   Started    5m (x2 over 5m)   kubelet, node2     Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy  4m (x3 over 5m)   kubelet, node2     Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.16.104.22:9200/_cluster/health: dial tcp 172.16.104.22:9200: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  4m (x4 over 5m)   kubelet, node2     Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 172.16.104.22:9300: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  51s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, node2     (combined from similar events): Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.16.104.22:9200/_cluster/health: EOF








root@node1:/home/arkan# k logs pod/es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7 -c es-data
[2018-07-18T18:46:13,037][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] initializing ...
[2018-07-18T18:46:13,267][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/data (/dev/mapper/node1--vg-root)]], net usable_space [13.8gb], net total_space [27.9gb], types [ext4]
[2018-07-18T18:46:13,270][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] heap size [247.5mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2018-07-18T18:46:13,272][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] node name [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7], node ID [ymKMhUIxRq-hbrmrqzayCQ]
[2018-07-18T18:46:13,272][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] version[6.3.0], pid[1], build[default/tar/424e937/2018-06-11T23:38:03.357887Z], OS[Linux/4.4.0-128-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_151/25.151-b12]
[2018-07-18T18:46:13,273][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xms256m, -Xmx256m, -Des.path.home=/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
[2018-07-18T18:46:15,832][WARN ][o.e.d.c.s.Settings       ] [http.enabled] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
[2018-07-18T18:46:18,327][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2018-07-18T18:46:18,331][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2018-07-18T18:46:18,331][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2018-07-18T18:46:18,332][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2018-07-18T18:46:18,332][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2018-07-18T18:46:18,337][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] no plugins loaded
[2018-07-18T18:46:26,419][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] parsed [0] roles from file [/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
[2018-07-18T18:46:28,422][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] using discovery type [zen]
[2018-07-18T18:46:30,218][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] initialized
[2018-07-18T18:46:30,218][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] starting ...
[2018-07-18T18:46:30,630][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] publish_address {172.16.104.22:9300}, bound_addresses {172.16.104.22:9300}
[2018-07-18T18:46:30,701][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2018-07-18T18:46:33,802][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:46:36,803][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:46:39,805][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
    [2018-07-18T18:46:43,830][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59678, remoteAddress=null}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:46:44,818][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59684, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:46:45,810][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:46:45,902][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59690, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:46:48,812][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:46:48,900][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59714, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:46:49,899][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59720, remoteAddress=null}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:46:51,815][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:46:51,901][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59730, remoteAddress=null}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:46:52,900][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59734, remoteAddress=null}]
 [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:46:59,897][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59782, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:00,781][WARN ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30s
[2018-07-18T18:47:00,801][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] publish_address {172.16.104.22:9200}, bound_addresses {172.16.104.22:9200}
[2018-07-18T18:47:00,803][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] started
[2018-07-18T18:47:00,821][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:02,896][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59796, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:03,822][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:06,823][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again

[2018-07-18T18:47:15,897][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59880, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:18,832][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:21,835][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:24,837][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:24,841][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59936, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:27,838][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:30,840][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:30,897][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59976, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:33,844][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:33,898][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:59992, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:36,847][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:51,854][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:51,897][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:60110, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:47:54,857][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:47:57,858][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again

[2018-07-18T18:48:06,897][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:60202, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:48:09,868][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:48:39,886][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:48:39,897][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:60418, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

[2018-07-18T18:49:15,909][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:49:15,997][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] send message failed [channel: NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:60640, remoteAddress=elasticsearch-discovery/172.16.166.167:9300}]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
[2018-07-18T18:49:18,910][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:49:21,912][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:49:24,913][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2018-07-18T18:49:27,915][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es-data-6fdbcf956f-fdnc7] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
```

Comment: This is the gist file for es-master, es-data, and VirtualService for Istio  https://gist.github.com/arkanmgerges/d284063b6b4d8bce941526ba1d6b62ca

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm running into a similar issue with ES on Istio. @arkan-m-gerges

Comment: @patrickbadley, I did not play with istio for a long time, since I put this question. The last time it worked using the autoinject as I remember. Please check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @arkan-m-gerges, I'm using auto-inject and still having issues.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: here are some links from github https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11120#issuecomment-536923536

Answer (score 3):

ElasticSearch expects to be able to talk to PodIPs directly.

Consider disabling the sidecar for ElasticSearch.

https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#policy documents how to use the `sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"` annotation.

Answer (score -1):

You can add namespace (`-n logging`) to your deploy script. For example

```
kubectl create -f es-discovery-svc.yaml -n logging
...
```

Istio sidecar autoinject only work on `namespace:default` by default.